# Ubuntu 12.4, 11.10 Crash/freeze at installation

Tags: 11.10, installation

Ubuntu is my primary operating system, and I DO NOT HAVE WINDOWS INSTALLED ANYMORE. When i try to install ubuntu 12.4 or 11.10, somewheare at 90% of the installation completed it either crashes, either it switches to the terminal (fullscreen if you know what i mean), or it will freeze. This has been ongoing for a while. i've tried different disks to install ubuntu, the flash drive, and even the low quallity graphics installer. i've tried many of they'se things, but none worked. my computer is Asus p5ql pro, ati radeon HD 3850, and intel dual core 3gh. PLEASE HELP!!! i dont want windows anymore, i just need linux.

Comment: This question should instead be filed as a bug report, thanks! [Instructions here](http://askubuntu.com/questions/5121/how-do-i-report-a-bug).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After boot from liveCD, In start menu[Try ubuntu/ install ubuntu/ etc] press F6 then select nomodeset. press ESC. Now select install ubuntu.

Also disconnect internet while installing. [image]

Comment: when i press F6 nothing happens

Comment: do you mean in the low quality graphics installer?

Comment: see the screenshot.

Answer (score 1):

Maybe first you have to hit **ESC** at the welcome screen(see picture attached), then select your language, then you get the "Try Ubuntu.." screen previously mentioned by Web-E..

[image]

Comment: it still freezes

Answer (score 0):

Ditto!same problem,Im using a older dell laptop, tried to load a fresh install of 12.4 ,about 90% of way through install everything just stops!Try this it worked for me 
1. load from cd iso as usual ,when asked to try umbuntu or install ubuntu opt to try ,once loaded on the screen you will see a install 12,4 icon click it and away you go,worked like a charm for me.
2.enjoy!

Answer (score 0):

On an ASUS?  Try this:

Go to BIOS > Security> I / O interface Security> "New interface card". Set it to Locked.

http://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=1662577&page=3